# How can I use vertical camera in navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia + android phone?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, camera, mediadevices

I'm trying to open cameras in portrait mode (vertically). It works fine in my development PCs (two desktops and a notebook) + chrome browser, but I'm failing to do the same in a debug android phone + chrome mobile.

I'm writing a vuejs2.x app, but this camera part is pure html+js:

```
const testAspectRatio = this.isLandscape() ? 1920/1080 : 1080/1920
const cameraConstraints = {
                    video: {
                        deviceId: deviceId,
                        aspectRatio: testAspectRatio,
                        // width: { ideal: this.isLandscape() ? 1920 : 1080 },//this.height,
                        // height: { ideal: this.isLandscape() ? 1080 : 1920 } //this.width
                    }
                }

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.cameraConstraints).then(stream => {
//...
```

What am I doing? In desktop browser both approaches seem to work fine: I can either ask for a desired `aspect ratio` or try to suggest ideal `width` and `height`. In mobile I can see in debug logs that I asked for vertical stream, like 1080 width X 1920 height, and the browser's api gives me a regular landscape (horizontal) stream.

How can I fix this behavior? What am I doing wrong?

Test phone is a poco x5 pro. Will try more phones (and emulated android) today =)

Comment: Hey, did you try, `facingMode: { exact: "user" }`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it will be helpful because I need to face environment (rear camera) =(

Comment: Not sure, it might be a case that aspectRatio is not supported by some devices. but instead of using aspect-ratio, can you explicitly calculate the width and height based on current AR? For example-  `let width = 0; let height = 0; if (this.isLandscape()) {
  width = 1920;
  height = Math.round(1920 / testAspectRatio);
} else {
  width = Math.round(1080 * testAspectRatio);
  height = 1080;
}` and then `video: { width: { ideal: width },height: { ideal: height }}`

Comment: It looks to me like your aspect ratio is backwards. It should be `height:width` e.g., `height/width` so I would expect `1080/1920` in the _landscape_ case - 

`testAspectRatio = this.isLandscape() ? 1920/1080 : 1080/1920` should be `testAspectRatio = this.isLandscape() ? 1080/1920 : 1920/1080`

Comment: Did you tried aspectRatio: `9/16` and vice versa `16/9` ?